# Unitary Operator on infinitely differentiable function

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, mathematical-physics, differential-operators

If $Ψ(x)$ is an infinitely differentiable function, And the operator $\widehat{D}=\exp(ax\frac{d}{dx})$, then show that $\widehat{D}Ψ(x) = Ψ(e^a x)$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I think it's correct even with your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $U(a, x):= \hat D_a\Psi(x)$, then we see that
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial U}{\partial a} = x\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}\ \ \text{ and } \ \ \ U(0, x) = \Psi(x).
\end{align}
Then we see that
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{da}U(a, x(a)) = 0
\end{align}
provided $x' = -x$. Hence it follows $x = x_0e^{-a}$ and $U(a, x(a)) = U(0, x_0)$. This means
\begin{align}
U(a, x) = U(0, e^a x) = \Psi(e^a x). 
\end{align}

Comment: Don't you think that U(0,x) = 1 and not Ψ(x).

Comment: @SHOURIEMRSS Observe the operator will be the identity. So when the identity acts on $\Psi$ you get back $\Psi$.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Do you think this problem can be solved by expanding the operator into a series and the summing it as a Taylor series?